# If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges with $a_n \geq 0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ also converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Given $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, with $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n \in \bf{N}$, I want to know whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ also converges.

Given the condition that $S_n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges with $a_n \geq 0$ $\forall n$, then $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n^2$ also converges (proved result).

In addition, it is not always the case that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n$ converges (counterexample: let $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$), although $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n$ converges.

I am trying to see if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ would converge given the previous information as well as the results that I have obtained above and given to me by theorems. I cannot seem to figure out any counterexamples (if at all). Note that the sum goes from $n = 1 \to \infty$, so no series of the form $a_n = \frac{1}{n^p(\ln{n})^q}$ cannot be used (as the case $n=1$ is left out).

I don't see a good comparison test nor other convergence tests to use, along with monotone-bounded or Cauchy series principles. I am also at a loss of certain theorems that may be handy.

Comment: No. Take $a_n=1/\sqrt{n}$ for $n=2^k$, and $0$ for all other $n$.

Comment: What's the real question? The one from the title or the one from the first sentence?

Comment: I'm guessing you forgot to mention that the sequence monotone decreases, because of both the counterexample by @ProfessorVector and your claim that $na_n$ converges?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I made an edit to make the question clearer in the title.

Comment: @AugustLiu Yes, the sequence will monotone decrease since if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges with $a_n \geq 0$, this necessitates that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = 0$ (the necessary condition). With additional work, it can also be shown that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n a_n = 0$ is also convergent.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Thanks for the example. However, I think your example does not converge at all, since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is not convergent to begin with, and thus I do not need to check whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ does not need to be checked. I am considering series of the form where $a_n$ is defined for all $n \in \bf{N} \setminus \{0\}$.

Comment: Please, reread it: $1/\sqrt{n}$ *only for* $n=2^k$! So the sum is $\sum^\infty_{k=0}2^{-k/2}$, that's converging very well.

Comment: But that means that means letting $a_n = 2^{\frac{-n}{2}}$, which converges as you have demonstrated, means that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ converges, and since $n a_n^2 \geq k a_k^2$, that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ also converges. By the comparison test, this means the sum of $k a_k^2$ also converges. Thus, this is not a counterexample showing divergence. I am trying to see either generally that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = L_n$ for some $L_n \in \bf{R}$ and $a_n \geq 0$ $\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ also converges. This example actually shows an example of convergence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Note that the statement is *true* if $a_n$ is monotone decreasing. Indeed, if $a_n$ is monotone decreasing and $S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k$ converges, then

$$ n a_n \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k \leq S, $$

and so,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S a_n = S^2. $$

**2.** Without monotonicity, we have a counter example as in **@Hagen von Eitzen**'s answer. As it seems that OP is not satisfied with a piecewise expression, here is a slight tweak of @Hagen von Eitzen's example:

$$ \bbox[10px,#ffd]{ a_n = \frac{\cos^{2n^2}(\pi n^{1/4})}{\sqrt{n}} } $$

The idea is that $\cos^{2n^2}(\pi n^{1/4})$ will take the value $1$ for $n = k^4$ but otherwise becomes almost zero, closely mimicking @Hagen von Eitzen's example.

To analyze the behavior of this sequence, for each $k \in \mathbb{N}_1 = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ we define

$$ I_k = \Bigl\{ n \in \mathbb{N}_1 : k-\tfrac{1}{2} < n^{1/4} \leq k+\tfrac{1}{2} \Bigr\}. $$

In the following answer, $c_1, c_2, \ldots$ are positive absolute constants whose values are not so important.

- First, it is useful to note that there exist absolute constants $c_1, c_2 \in (0, \infty)$ such that

  $$ c_1 k^4 \leq n \leq c_2 k^4 \tag{1} $$

  for all $k \in \mathbb{N}_1$ and for all $n \in I_k$.
- Next, fix $k \in \mathbb{N}_1$ and consider $n \in I_k$. Also, write $n = k^4 + r$. Then by the mean value theorem and $\text{(1)}$,

  $$ \left| n^{1/4} - k \right|
  = \left| (k^4 + r)^{1/4} - (k^4)^{1/4} \right|
  \geq \frac{r}{4\max\{k^4+r,k^4\}^{3/4}}
  \geq \frac{c_3 r}{k^3} \tag{2} $$

  for $c_3 = \frac{1}{4\max\{c_2^{3/4},1\}}$. Now using the inequality $\cos(\pi x) \leq 1 - 4x^2$ for $\left| x \right| \leq \frac{1}{2}$,

  $$ \left| \cos(\pi n^{1/4}) \right|
  = \cos(\pi (n^{1/4} - k))
  \leq 1 - 4(n^{1/4} - k)^2
  \leq 1 - \frac{c_4 r^2}{k^3} $$

  for $c_4 = 4c_3^2$. Then by using the inequality $1 - x \leq e^{-x}$, we get

  $$ \cos^{2n^2}(\pi n^{1/4}) \leq \left( 1 - \frac{c_4 r^2}{k^3} \right)^{2n^2} \leq e^{-c_5 k r^2}. $$

  for $c_5 = 2c_1c_4$. So it follows that

  $$ a_n \leq \frac{c_6}{k^2} e^{-c_5 k r^2}. $$

  for $c_6 = c_1^{-1/2}$.

Combining altogether, we have

\begin{align*}
S
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n \in I_k} a_n
\leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{r=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{c_6}{k^2} e^{-c_5 k r^2}
< \infty.
\end{align*}

On the other hand,

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n^2
\geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^4 a_{k^4}^2
= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1
= \infty. $$

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$ a_n=\begin{cases}\frac1{k^2}&\text{if }n=k^4\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to look at $a_n$ that is defined over all $n \in \bf{N} \setminus \{0\}$, so this $a_n$ would not fit this description. Would there be any function that is defined over all $n = \{1, 2, 3, ....\}$ such that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges (and $a_n \geq 0$), then can I say whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ converges or there is an example of divergence?

Comment: @qxzsilver, What do you mean? The example $a_n$ given in this answer **is** defined for all $n=1,2,3,\dots$.

Comment: I mean that the values of all numbers in the natural numbers that are not a 4th power are all set to 0. Besides, this series is still convergent by the comparison test since the given $a_n < \frac{1}{n^2}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ also converges. Now, $n a_n^2 < n \frac{1}{n^4} < \frac{1}{n^3}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n a_n^2$ also converges. This does not constitute a counterexample showing divergence, nor does it prove convergence given the conditions.

Comment: I should note that some of the "less than (<)" symbols should be $\leq$ instead in my previous comment

Comment: @qxzsilver, (1) I suspect that you want some "non-piecewise" example. (2) You are misunderstanding this example. Note that Hagen von Eitzen's example can be recast as $$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}&\text{if $n=k^4$ for some $k$},\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases},$$ and so, $ na_n^2 =1 $ whenever $n=k^4$. This is enough to check that $\sum_n na_n^2$ diverges.

Comment: @SangchulLee Yes, I did misunderstand this example. Thanks for this example, now I understood it properly.